# Can't find Web Application project in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans-plugins

When I start a netbeans project, there is no categories "Java Web". Which is for make "Web Application" project. How can I add "java web" plugin or something in netbeans to see the java web categories in categories list in netbeans. please someone help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go to the Tools menu and select Plugins. Then click on the "Available Plugins" tab.
2. Check the box for "Java Web Applications".
3. Click the "Install" button.
4. Click your way through the dialogs until the plugin and its dependencies are installed.
5. Restart the IDE.

You should now find "Java Web" in File -> New Project.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that has this issue I've figured out how to fix it (when you find find the files for your webproject in htdocs).

Click on File -> New Project
Then click on Php Application from Existing Sources...
Then click on the files you have in your htdocs folder and it should show back up.
(Note you might have to double check the port numbers when you set it back up).